# Send a particular row of a table to a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hello I am trying to extract a particular rows data from a html table that is filled by ng repeat

```
<script> var wmodel=function(s) { alert(s); } </script>
```

the table

```
<body> <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> <table><tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="wmodel(this.x)"> View details</a> </td>
```

But i am getting x as undefined pls help

Comment: are you able to access names in your html?

Comment: If you are able to access names then you should be able to get "x.Name" else check your JSON and Why are you passing "this.x" in wmodel,In your case you should pass only x in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="wmodel(x)"> View details </a>
```

In controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.wmodel = function (s) {
        alert(s);
    };
}]);
```